# spring-boot project don't evaluate thymeleaf custom processors

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, dialect

For some reason, my current spring-boot project is not evaluating my custom thymeleaf tags. i have the dialects registered in my Application class like that:

```
  @Bean
  public FormDialect formDialect() {
    return new FormDialect();
  }
```

the dialects reference the processors this way:

```
public class FormDialect extends AbstractDialect {
  public String getPrefix() {
    return null;
  }

  public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors() {
    final Set<IProcessor> processors = new HashSet<IProcessor>();
    processors.add(new com.loja.thymeleaf.processor.form.FormProcessor());
    return processors;
  }
}
```

but when I open a page with a code like that:

```
      <Form ...>
        <Fieldset type="Input" class="form-group">
          <Label></Label>
          <Input class="form-control"></Input>
        </Fieldset>

        <Fieldset type="Select" class="form-group">
          <Label></Label>
          <Select class="form-control"></Select>
        </Fieldset>

        <Fieldset type="Textarea" class="form-group">
          <Label></Label>
          <Textarea class="form-control"></Textarea>
        </Fieldset>
      </Form>
```

the processors are not being evaluated into the final code. Anyone can see what's wrong here? This was working in this project, and suddently (after some change I don't recall what was) stop working.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing my working code, you may missing `@Configuration` annotation.

```
@Configuration
public class YourThymeleafConfig {
  @Bean
  public FormDialect formDialect() {
    return new FormDialect();
  }
}
```

and you should define prefix

```
public class FormDialect extends AbstractDialect {
  @Override
  public String getPrefix() {
    return "some_prefix";
  }

  @Override
  public Set<IProcessor> getProcessors() {
    final Set<IProcessor> processors = new HashSet<IProcessor>();
    processors.add(new com.loja.thymeleaf.processor.form.FormProcessor());
    return processors;
  }
}
```

template

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:some_prefix="http://xxx">
  <!-- ... -->
  <Form some_prefix:your_diarect_attribute="...">
    <!-- ... -->
  </Form>
</html>
```

`your_diarect_attribute` is corresponding to `org.thymeleaf.processor.AttributeNameProcessorMatcher#attributeName`

`AttributeNameProcessorMatcher` is extended by `com.loja.thymeleaf.processor.form.FormProcessor`

Comment: the dialect declaration already had the annotation `@SpringBootApplication`, equivalent to declaring with `@Configuration`, `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and `@ComponentScan`. and according to this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/418 it's possible create a dialect without prefix.